# iptables match multiport - need clarification : dport or dports , sport or sports

Tags: iptables

What is the best practice, I mean when not using the long version -destination-port or -source-port

We often see both on various web sites. Iptables.info never speaks of --dports or --sports.... what do you say please?

Answer (score 1):

From [`man iptables-extensions`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/iptables-extensions.8.html):

```
multiport
   This module matches a set of source or destination  ports.   Up  to  15
   ports  can be specified.  A port range (port:port) counts as two ports.
   It can only be used in conjunction with one of the following protocols:
   tcp, udp, udplite, dccp and sctp.

   [!] --source-ports,--sports port[,port|,port:port]...
          Match  if  the  source port is one of the given ports.  The flag
          --sports is a convenient alias for this option.  Multiple  ports
          or  port ranges are separated using a comma, and a port range is
          specified using a colon.  53,1024:65535  would  therefore  match
          ports 53 and all from 1024 through 65535.

   [!] --destination-ports,--dports port[,port|,port:port]...
          Match  if  the  destination port is one of the given ports.  The
          flag --dports is a convenient alias for this option.

   [!] --ports port[,port|,port:port]...
          Match if either the source or destination ports are equal to one
          of the given ports.
```

Comment: Thanks man, and for the link too. I wandered where I already read about aliases. In the lap time, I discovered that even very short one work too : --dp & --sp